# Using NOT IN and OR not working as intended in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm attempting to write a query that will allow me to get any record from one table if the id doesn't exist in another table, or if it does exist and it also meets a second criteria. Below is what I attempted to do, but it always returns 0 rows:

```
SELECT p.pageid, p.pager FROM pages p, updates u
WHERE p.pageid NOT IN (SELECT pageid FROM updates)
   OR (p.pageid = u.pageid AND u.pagenums > 1000) LIMIT 100
```

From what I can tell this *should* work, but it's not. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm guessing you're receiving some error having to do with your "updates" table being called "update"

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. The table/column names are all correct.

Comment: the first "update" table  should be "updates" ?

Comment: You should also specify a `JOIN` condition since this is creating a cartesian product.

Comment: Yes, fixed that. The table is "updates".

Comment: Do you have any `NULL` `pageid` values in `updates`?

Comment: There are nulls, yes. Would that be the problem?

Comment: @user485418  `NOT IN (subquery containing NULL)` always returns no results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try with this query

```
select p.pageid, p.pager from pages p where p.pageid not in (select pageid from updates)
union
select p.pageid,p.pager from pages p, updates u where p.pageid = u.pageid and u.pagenums > 1000
```

Comment: I think this may be exactly what I was looking for, thank you.